# How can an object in Scala be cast to the intersection of its own type and any unrelated trait?

Tags: scala, types, casting, traits

Consider the following:

```
trait Foo { def bar: Any }
```

Now, `3` and `X` don't even have a method `bar` yet this compiles:

```
val a = 3.asInstanceOf[Int with Foo]

object X
val b = X.asInstanceOf[X.type with Foo]
```

This code, when compiled and run (on Scala 2.10.3), produces no error. However, the following *will* compile cleanly but will produce a `ClassCastException` at runtime:

```
val a1 = a.asInstanceOf[Foo]
val b1 = b.asInstanceOf[Foo]
```

How can this be? I can almost accept the fact that no static analysis/checking is performed on explicit casts, and they're discouraged and usually unneeded anyway—although I do think Scala *could* emit a warning about a definitely incorrect type cast given that there is no way `object X` can ever have the trait `Foo`, nor an integer—however I can't easily accept the fact that an integer can be cast at runtime to an intersection type containing a completely irrelevant *and* non-empty trait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that JVM doesn't support intersection types, so there is no obvious runtime equivalent to `asInstanceOf[Int with Foo]`. This is basically the same issue as `asInstanceOf[T]`, where `T` is a generic parameter (both in Scala and equivalent Java): you also have the cast which appears to succeed at runtime but actually inserts casts in later code which uses methods of `T`.

One possibility would be to compile the cast to `Int with Foo` as two casts to `Int` and to `Foo`, but this doesn't quite work in general (e.g. when there is no runtime cast to `Foo` itself, or when the value is passed to methods which take `Int with Foo`).

Comment: Interesting... but then why doesn't Scala warn or error out?

Comment: Because, as you say, "no static analysis/checking is performed on explicit casts". You'll only get a `ClassCastException` if you actually try to call `a.bar` because that's where the real cast to `Foo` happens, same as in the case of cast to `T`.

Comment: OK, I guess that's something we have to live with on the JVM until Oracle addresses this in far future.